# FCM Notification not showing when app killed on some devices

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am working with ionic 3,

Some of the devices not receiving FCM notifications when the app is killed on Android.
Most common devices are Oppo, Vivo, and Xiaomi.

I've tested two plugin

https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

and

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

Comment: You will also recognize later that some design will also not run on them except if you minimize the app then open it or multi press, itried in xiomi device and these kind of devices (not like samsung,hawawie....) have some kind of bugs related to software and this bug is not from the app..

Comment: So what will be the solution for these devices? @MostafaHarb

Comment: Try to use different notification like oneSignal or there notification services provided by cordova . Try oneSignal, although it uses google services by fcm to send the notification, but onesifnal is integrated its service to get like 100% of devices . Give it a try on one signal